# If the global temperature rose by 20 degrees Celsius, would the freezing temperature of water drop 20 degrees?

Tags: hard-science, climate, atmosphere

Title says it all. Might be a silly question?

Comment: Hello Toodle. I am voting that question to be closed because it is not about worldbuilding. As a subject it would probably fit better on [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/). But I nevertheless discourage you to ask it there as there aren't any relationship between the physical properties of water and the climate.

Comment: I further suggest you to read the [tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), to know what kind of question you can ask here.

Comment: But it is about worldbuilding. I'm writing a myth in which the global temperature of a planet rises by about 20 degrees Celsius. I wanted to know if that would lower water's freezing point (or I suppose everything's freezing point) by 20 degrees. If It's 20 degrees hotter worldwide, then wouldn't it have to be 20 degrees cooler to reach that change in state?

Comment: I understand that your +20°C climate is probably for a world of your own, but asking about the freezing temperature of water IS about physics. Worldbuilding involves many different parts, and sometimes one needs to ask those somewhere else. In anycase, the answer to your question is: "No".

Comment: Fascinating.  If the water were initially at 50°C, then it would require cooling by 50°C to reach 0°C.  At 20 degrees warmer, or 70°C, then it would need to drop an additional 20° to reach 0°C, because if it dropped 50°C then it would reach 20°C.  Puts me to mind of a bizarre fever dream.

Answer (score 6):

No, it wouldn't. The temperature at which water freezes is decided by the physical properties of the H<sub>2</sub>O molecule. If I can put it in a slightly silly way, how would a water molecule in one part of the world "know" what the temperature is on the other side of the world is anyway?

Freezing and boiling points of all substances, not just water, do vary with *pressure*. See [this link to Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60170/freezing-point-of-water-with-respect-to-pressure). The effect on water is slight under conditions normally met with by humans on Earth.

For interest, I will mention that phenomena such as [supercooling](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/at-what-temperature-does-water-freeze-1120813/?no-ist) and [the Mpemba effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mpemba_effect) do introduce complications to the question of the temperature at which water freezes - but they are nothing like what you describe.

If, as you say, you are writing a myth, I suggest that you put it all down to the wrath of the god Neptune.